# Sentry is working on local but not working in server

Tags: python-3.x, django, error-handling, sentry

I'm troubled with the sentry, I configured sentry in my Django application it's working fine and an error arrives in sentry UI from localhost, but in the same case, I run from the server it's not working, and no error arrives into sentry UI.

```
DEBUG=False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]

sentry_sdk.init(
        dsn="https://sentry-url",
    
        integrations=[DjangoIntegration(), CeleryIntegration(), RedisIntegration()],
        # Set traces_sample_rate to 1.0 to capture 100%
        # of transactions for performance monitoring.
        # We recommend adjusting this value in production.
        traces_sample_rate=1.0,
        # If you wish to associate users to errors (assuming you are using
        # django.contrib.auth) you may enable sending PII data.
        send_default_pii=True,
    )
```